# How to seperate prefix from a dynamic text before printing in BIRT

Tags: eclipse, birt

The name which i want to print in the report as a dynamic text is in the encrypted format in the DB. I decrypt this name with the help of the following script in onCreate of this dynamic text field.

```
this.text=Packages.com.erp.util.EncryptUtil.decrypt(name);
```

Now the problem is, this name comes with the prefix Mr,Ms etc concatenated with the name in some reports which is affecting the name decryption, I want the name alone for decrypt. Separating the prefix and name in query is disturbing the binding and leads to some other errors. So what i want to do is check the name for any space or split so that i can identify after the 1st space whatever coming would be the name and before space would be prefix. Then i want to send that name alone to the `decypt` method and on returning decrypted name should concatenate with the prefix using some script and print in the dynamic text field. How to achieve this in the BIRT Report Designer Version: 3.7.1.v2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `DataSet` Drag and drop the name attribute into the report somewhere and make it invisible. Go to the `onRender` of that name attribute which available from the script tab in BIRT and paste the following code to separate prefix from name and send the name alone to your method.

```
name = this.getValue();
var sArr  = name.split(" ");
name="";
for(var i=1;i<sArr.length;i++){
if(sArr[i]!=null)
name = name+" "+sArr[i];
}
name = name.replace(/^[ ]+|[ ]+$/g,'')
name=sArr[0]+" "+Packages.com.yourpackagename.yourmethodname(name);
```

Now drag and drop the dynamic text from the palette to the position where you want see the name. Go to the `onCreate` of that dynamic text field which available from the script tab and paste the following code to print the result which returned from your method along with the prefix.

```
this.text=name;
```